# /var/jenkins_home/workspace/John-Test@tmp/durable-2e590c15/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found

Tags: docker, jenkins

i am running jenkins as follows: (in other words as a docker container on a centos vm), note that this command has privileged flag, i was trying to see if this would make a difference, but not.

```
docker run --privileged -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v /home/llnt.local/sbollapragada/sbollasjenkinsconfig:/var/jenkins_home jenkinsci/blueocean
```

when i run a pipeline script like this one:

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'maven:3.3.3' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i am seeing this error:

```
Console Output
Started by user Shan
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/John-Test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . maven:3.3.3
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/John-Test@tmp/durable-2e590c15/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull maven:3.3.3
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/John-Test@tmp/durable-4d643ceb/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

any ideas of how to resolve this issue, i want the jenkins container to use the docker running in the vm (host machine). any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

After a lot of research, I found out that we cannot use `docker` in a Jenkins container.

Try to install Jenkins directly on your CentOS VM and check. If you still have the same issue this means that I'm wrong. If not, you can mark this response as a good one.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a bit old, but I just had a very similar issue due (I think) to crossing fs types.

I had jenkins_home on a vfat fs with a symlink to my working directory on my Ubuntu system (ext4).

After moving jenkins_home to my local ext4 fs the problem went away.

Perhaps the OP is having the same issue because the Virtual Machine is running on a windows system and the jenkins_home fs does not have support for linux permissions?

Good luck :D